# Files.list yields unpredictable results

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the Drive API's [File List](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) method to lists the content of a drive. There are 8 files in the drive (4 in the main folder, and another 4 in a subfolder). Last week, I used the method and successfully retrieved the 8 files.

This week however, when I tried, I first only got 5 files:

[image]

After accessing the drive, and trying the method again, I now get 7 files:

[image]

Note that this is still not correct. There should be a second "ConnectorDefinition.xml" file in the list, totaling 8.

The query is near-vanilla, with only "mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false" as "q" parameter. Removing it yield an additional result (the folder), but not the missing file (nor a trashed file that SHOULD appear now).

What can cause these differences? Nothing has changed in the sharing parameters or in the drive or account since last week.

Comment: What is the complete request that you do for this?

Comment: In the code (some fields removed): `FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();`
`listRequest.PageSize = 1000;`
`listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(appProperties,capabilities,contentHints,createdTime,description,explicitlyTrashed,fileExtension,folderColorRgb,fullFileExtension,headRevisionId,iconLink,id,imageMediaMetadata,isAppAuthorized,kind,lastModifyingUser,md5Checksum,mimeType,modifiedByMeTime,modifiedTime,name,originalFilename,ownedByMe,owners,parents,permissions)";`
`listRequest.Q = "mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false";`

Comment: Those 5 files are all files with special sharing settings (shared with one person, shared with a link, public etc). The two that show up after refreshing have no sharing settings (so only visible by the owner), and the one that doesn't show up at all also doesn't have sharing settings, and is in the subfolder.

Comment: Is the one that didn't show up, is only the files that inside a folder/subfolder?

Comment: Actually it turned out the one that didn't show up was in the main folder. I renamed it, and then it showed up. So it seems that private files only appear when they're accessed/edited...

Comment: ^ this is unlikely to be the explanation (and if it is, it's a serious bug). As I mentioned in my answer, Drive makes no assurances that all files will be in a single files.list response, only that they will be within a set of responses bounded by nextPageToken. Drive is massively distributed/async in nature and what files get included/excluded in a response is down to timings. It may be that by updating a file, it becomes cached and so gets included in the first response, whereas otherwise it would cold and deferred to a subsequent response.

Answer (score 2):

The spec of files.list does **not** guarantee that PageSize results will be returned, nor that repeated calls will return the same number of results. The only safe way to use files.list is within a loop until nextPageToken is null/undefined.

NB. This answer may or may not be the problem that you're experiencing. I'm posting it as something you need to consider and eliminate. I suggest doing a test with PageSize set to 1, so you can confirm that your code correctly iterates on nextPageToken.

Comment: My code is looping until nextPageToken is null yeah. I checked now, and it seems to work.

Comment: So to confirm, if you set PageSize=1, does your loop iterate 8 times before nextPageToken==null, or does it terminate prematurely?

Comment: It iterates until nextPageToken is null, yes.

Comment: and iterates 8 times if you set pagesize=1?